# C++ - Why comparison not working on char?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a simple calculator in C++ . But every time my code throws me an error though I think it's right, Sorry for any unwilling mistake. I'm a newbie in C++ .

my code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char symbol;
int x,y;
cout<<"What operation you want to do?\n+ - * / : ";
cin>>symbol;
if(symbol != '+' || symbol != '-' || symbol != '*' || symbol != '/')
    cout<<"Wrong symbol chosen."<<endl;
else
{
    cout<<"Enter two numbers. separate with space : ";
    cin>> x >> y;
    if(symbol == '+')
        cout<<x<<" + "<<y<<" = "<<x+y<<endl;
    else if(symbol == '-')
        cout<<x<<" - "<<y<<" = "<<x-y<<endl;
    else if(symbol == '*')
        cout<<x<<" * "<<y<<" = "<<x*y<<endl;
    else if(symbol == '/')
        cout<<x<<" / "<<y<<" = "<<x/y<<endl;
//}

return 0;
}
```

Each time i run this, put a symbol( +, -, * or /) & then it shows me "Wrong symbol chosen." , I don't understand why this is happening. I'm using Code::Blocks v 16 on windows 10 .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look closely at your `if` condition and read it out loud.

Comment: `symbol` will always be not equal to at least three of those.

Comment: `symbol` cannot be both `+` and `-` at the same time, so one of the first two conditions is *always* true.

Comment: as long as one statement in that if statement is true, then your if statement will execute because you are using OR. For example, if  + is your input, then your statement will look like this                                                 
        if(F ||T || T|| T)    which evaluates to true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition is wrong!.

```
if(symbol != '+' || symbol != '-' || symbol != '*' || symbol != '/')
    cout<<"Wrong symbol chosen."<<endl;
```

Change the above condition with this -

```
if(symbol != '+' && symbol != '-' && symbol != '*' && symbol != '/')
    cout<<"Wrong symbol chosen."<<endl;
```